# pyqt webkit + divx web player

Tags: python, webkit, pyqt, web, divx

I know this is probably impossible, but let's try asking anyway: what I would like to do is using the divx web player plugin within a page rendered by pythoh qt4 webkit widget. I mean: in page.html I put the standard divx web player embed code, then I load it with webkit pyqt and (magic) it works and plays my video. Do you think this is possible?

Thanks to all!
Marco

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see what happens?

Comment: I've just tried it and it doesn't work by default...

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to set it to enabled using the QWebSettings, according to the [documentation](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwebsettings.html#globalSettings).

I'd try something like

```
QWebSettings.globalSettings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
```

and see if it enables the plugins.